# Python slice array to get all but some index

Tags: python, arrays, slice

Is it possible to use python's slicing to get all but some item of a given array?

meaning, for example,

```
arr = range(10)
print(slicing_magic(arr, 4))
```

would output

```
[0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9]
```

I realize this could be done with

```
def slicing_magic(arr, ind):
    return arr[0:ind] + arr[ind+1:]
```

I wonder if there is a way without list addition, or

**what is the most pythonic way?**

Comment: @Aran-Fey not a duplicate.. I stated the obvious answer and that I am searching for a prettier one

Comment: All the sensible ways to do it are there. If you can't find anything "prettier", that's because nothing exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this?

```py
def magic_slicer(arr, idx):
    b = arr.copy()
    del b[idx]
    return b
```

Comment: Yeah I fixed it.